# Getting Rails4-StarterKit setup in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to get [this starter app](https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit) working. My first issue was receiving the error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken` after clicking any Sign Up or Log In links, as well as any links that should send an email. I fixed this problem by chaning the line `protect_from_forgery :with => :exception` in my Application Controller to   `protect_from_forgery :with => :null_session`. Now, clicking any of the above buttons just redirects me to the Sign Up page, instead of signing the user in to their profile.

I think that this should be easily reproducible by cloning the Github repo. All I did was run a `bundle install` and `rake db:create`, which both worked fine.

**PS**

I'm also receiving this error. Not sure if it's related. Actually, there's no `contacts\new` view inside the StarterKit app, I believe it's from another app of mine; it's a view which allows the user to send an email. But the message is coming from the server running StarterKit app... strange. I guess I'll have to figure out what Dalli::Server is.

```
Started GET "/contacts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 00:23:44 -0500
Started GET "/contacts/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-12-11 00:23:44 -0500
Cache read: _session_id:d0fd8ec75b1e5f9c0a0088a62a8df251
Cache read: _session_id:d0fd8ec75b1e5f9c0a0088a62a8df251
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
Dalli::Server#connect 127.0.0.1:11211
127.0.0.1:11211 failed (count: 8) Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe - write
127.0.0.1:11211 failed (count: 8) Errno::EPIPE: Broken pipe - write
127.0.0.1:11211 is still down (for 260.077 seconds now)
127.0.0.1:11211 is still down (for 260.077 seconds now)
DalliError: No server available
DalliError: No server available
```

Anyways, I'm not experienced enough to figure this all out on my own, so I'd really appreciate if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that you haven't started `memcached`. Look at the [Installation](https://github.com/starterkits/rails4-starterkit) section, you'll see the following command for starting `memcached` on OSX

```
/usr/local/opt/memcached/bin/memcached
```

Comment: Thanks. I installed memcached, though my terminal doesn't output anything after running that command, it just hangs. Is that normal?

Comment: @portOdin To ensure that memcached was started properly, run your Rails app and you should not see the error that you posted. Or you can also check if memcached is running on port 11211.